# Run a process asynchronously and read from stdout and stderr

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some code that runs a process and reads from the stdout and stderr asynchronously and then handles when the process completes. It looks something like this:

```
Process process = builder.start();

    Thread outThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            // Read stream here
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    });

    Thread errThread = new Thread(() -> {
      try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
        // Read stream here
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
    });

    outThread.start();
    errThread.start();

    new Thread(() -> {
      int exitCode = -1;
      try {
        exitCode = process.waitFor();
        outThread.join();
        errThread.join();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

    // Process completed and read all stdout and stderr here
    }).start();
```

My issue is with the fact that I am using 3 threads to achieve this asynchronous "run-and-get-output" task - I don't know why, but I feel it doesn't feel right using 3 threads. I could allocate the threads out of a thread pool, but that would still be blocking those threads.

Is there anything I can do, maybe with NIO, to reduce this to fewer (1?) thread? Anything I can think of will be constantly spinning a thread (unless I add a few sleeps), which I don't really want to do either...

**NOTE: I do need to read as I go (rather than when the process has stopped) and I do need to separate stdin from stderr so can't do a redirect.**

Comment: I don't think you need that last thread. Unless you need to run multiple of these in a loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - what you see there is inside a method called `runAsync(String command)` which I need to return immediately (its asynchronous). How would I can handle the exit code of the process and that the reading of the streams completing without that extra thread?

Comment: Given that, I think you need all three threads then.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've specified that you need to read the output as you go, there is no non-multi-threaded solution.

You can reduce the number of threads to one beyond your main thread though:

```
Process process = builder.start();
Thread errThread = new Thread(() -> {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
      // Read stream here
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
});
errThread.start();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
        // Read stream here
} catch (Exception e) {
}
// we got an end of file, so there can't be any more input.  Now we need to wait for stderr/process exit.

int exitCode = -1;
try {
    exitCode = process.waitFor();
    errThread.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
}

// Process completed
```

If you truely don't need to deal with the error/output until after the process ends, you can simplify it a bit and only use your main thread like this:

```
    File stderrFile = File.createTempFile("tmpErr", "out");
    File stdoutFile = File.createTempFile("tmpStd", "out");
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ls /tmp");
        Process p = builder.start();
        int exitCode = -1;
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            try {
                exitCode = p.waitFor();
                done = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted waiting for process to exit.");
            }
        }
        BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stderrFile));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stdoutFile));
        ....
    } finally {
        stderrFile.delete();
        stdoutFile.delete();
    }
```

This is probably not a good idea if you generate a lot of output from the process you are calling as it could run out of disk space... but it'll likely be slightly faster since it doesn't have to spin up another Thread.

Comment: If you don't actually read from err and in your process may get stuck fairly quickly.

Comment: It is reading from both. Basically the only improvement here is that you don't need a separate thread to wait for the process to exit. It can't exit till the stdout is closed.

Comment: This is not the way to go, because it only works for a really small output. If the output is relatively big (maybe above 1kB?), your main thread will certainly get stuck.

Comment: @LucioPaiva how so? "Read stream here" should involve some sort of loop.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't mind the input and error streams to be merged, you could only use one thread with:

```
builder.redirectErrorStream(true); //merge input and error streams
Process process = builder.start();

Thread singleThread = new Thread(() -> {
  int exitCode = -1;
  //read from the merged stream
  try (BufferedReader reader = 
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    //read until the stream is exhausted, meaning the process has terminated
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line); //use the output here
    }
    //get the exit code if required
    exitCode = process.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception e) { }
}).start();
```

Comment: Read the note at the bottom :)

Comment: I missed that - I don't think there is much you can do then. Why is it a problem to use 3 threads in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ExecHelper](http://ostermiller.org/utils/src/ExecHelper.java.html) from OstermillerUtils.

The idea is that the thread waiting for the process to complete, does not just wait but reads input from stdout and stderr if there is input available and regurarly checks if the process has finished.

If you do not do any heavy processing with the input from stdout and stderr, you might not need an extra thread to handle the input. Just copy ExecHelper and add some extra functions/methods to process any new input. I've done this before to show the process output while the process is running, it is not difficult to do (but I lost the source code).

If you do need a separate thread for processing the input, make sure to synchronize the output and error StringBuffers when these buffers are updated or read.

Another thing you might want to consider is adding an abort time-out. It is a little bit harder to implement but was very valuable to me: if a process takes too much time, the process gets destroyed which in turn ensures nothing remains hanging. You can find an old (outdated?) example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fwi/51d980b0694dd9765520be83d67d2a18).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compromise. Here are your options:

A. You can do it with 2 threads (instead of 3):

First thread:

1. read from `stdout` until `readline` returns `null`
2. call `Process.waitFor()`
3. `join` Thread#2

Second thread:

1. reads from `stderr` until `readline` returns null

B. Merge streams and use Debian's `annotate-output` to discriminate the 2 streams

http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=annotate-output&sektion=1

C. If it's a short-living process just wait for the end of it

D. If it's a long-living process then you can spin between readers with some sleep in between.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer for people coming from Kotlin. This looks easy with Kotlin coroutines:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.produce
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

const val CONSOLE_MAX_LIFE = 1000000L

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun f(scope: CoroutineScope) {
    fun executeCommand(command: String): Process {
        val builder = ProcessBuilder()
        return builder.command(*command.split(" ").toTypedArray()).start()
    }
    val process = executeCommand("cmd args")
    val stdoutReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
    val stderrReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.errorStream))

    val stdoutChannel = scope.produce(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var line: String
        while (stdoutReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) { send(line) }
    }
    val stderrChannel = scope.produce(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var line: String
        while (stderrReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) { send(line) }
    }
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (true) {
            val line = stdoutChannel.receive()
            if (line.contains("xyz"))
                setProgressIndication(Pair(.5f, "5/10"))
        }
    }
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (true) {
            val line = stderrChannel.receive()
            if (line.contains("abc"))
                throw Exception()
        }
    }
    scope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
        process.onExit().get()
        stdoutChannel.cancel()
        stderrChannel.cancel()
    }
    scope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(CONSOLE_MAX_LIFE)
        process.destroy()
    }
}
```

This uses 6 coroutines, 2 for stdout, 2 for stderr. One for the sender channel, one for the receiver for each stdout/err, and finally one to close channels after process termination, and one for killing the terminal.