# BufferedReader.readLine blocks my program but BufferedReader.read() reads properly

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a snippet as follows:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
String line = br.readLine();
```

Now in the above code I am sure that process will always have on line input, so I did not use any kind of while loop or any null check. The problem is readLine blocks. The one reason I was aware of is, the stream having no data to read and hence readLine keeps waiting. To check this, I removed readLine and used read() function as follows:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
int a;
while((a=br.read())!=-1){
    char ch = (char) a;
    if(ch == '\n')
        System.out.print("New line "+ch);
    if(ch == '\r')
        System.out.print("Carriage return "+ch);
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```

To my surprise this code worked and printed the messags New line and Carriage return. Now I am wondering why did the readLine block? The data is available it is terminated by newline. What else could be the reason??

Note: The above worked once in a while! Maybe once out of 15times.
Note: I tried using ProcessBuilder too, but same behaviour.

UPDATE:
So I switched to ProcessBuilder and then I redirected the errorStream and now I get both input stream and error stream at once when I do process.getInputStream and this works fine. Below is the snippet.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
pb..redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line = br.readLine();
//Now I get both input and error stream.
```

I would like to differentiate my error stream from input stream but with this method they are all jumbled up! Any ideas on this?

Comment: what's the size of the data you read trying to read?

Comment: Could be anything from ~1kb to 50kb

Comment: and I am checking for error stream, so does size of file matter?

Comment: Another note: I am running a command on the file

Comment: You are reading from "reader" in the second example and from "br" in the first. Where is "reader" coming from?

Comment: That was a typo! It is br itself.

Comment: What JDK are you running this on?

Comment: JDK: 1.7.0_07. One more thing is that this error occurs frequently but once in a while it just works!!

Comment: Your readLine()-example works sometimes, your read()-example always? Or works your readLine() example also always if you wait long enough?

Comment: readLine() works only when I debug and wait for a long long time and that too only sometimes! It looks to me like data was not flushed into error stream. Might that be the reason?

Comment: Could be. If it is possible to change the called process in that way, that it flushes the buffers more frequently it may be helps.
Or, is it needed, that you read the error output while the process - maybe - is still running? If not, wait until process has ended before start reading.

Comment: I read it while it is running and the problem is I have no control on that executable. I will try to wait till its over and then try. I will update soon

Comment: Updated the question. Using ProcessBuilder and rediretErrorStream seems to get me half way.

Comment: Waiting for the process to finish is pointless and possibly counter-productive. Just block. If you want the output and error streams separate, don't merge them, and read them separately, in separate threads.

Comment: Well thats what I was doing first, treating error stream separately. But the readLine was blocking me! The above change seems to fulfill my requirements, but I am wondering why does redirectErrorStream make things work! Not sure what is going wrong!

Comment: The `readLine()` *will* block until a line is available to be read, or end of stream or an exception occurs. What's the problem with that exactly?

Comment: Related to your updated question, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25090132/3080094). The mentioned "ExecHelper" works without additional threads and prevents blocking on reading err/out streams.

Comment: @EJP Problem is that reading just from error stream does not work, readline is blocking like it is waiting.
vanOekel using ready is one way, I will try this method. Thanks

Comment: in your example you read ONE line - is this just in your snippet and you read ALL lines in your real code? please let me know (might be too obvious, so please don't feel offended)

Comment: Yes I read only one line of code. As I am sure it will have only one line and I am interested only in that.

Comment: have you tried a `while (line != null) { line = br.readLine(); }` just out of curiosity? maybe you get a simple line break before you want to read your desired line?

Comment: you mean: `while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) { do something}` well even there it does not work, because we do read a line and check if it is not null, and if so then we do some operations. Problem is the readLine never returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to avoid getting the error stream and input stream merged just remove the line 
`pb.redirectErrorStream(true);`

Because as said in the java doc :

> if this property is true, then any error output generated by subprocesses subsequently started by this object's start() method will be merged with the standard output, so that both can be read using the Process.getInputStream() method. This makes it easier to correlate error messages with the corresponding output. The initial value is false.

By calling `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` you are merging both output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use threads, in order to avoid it.

Like One slave thread which will be responsible for reading. This will not halt your progress of program.

Comment: I want the program to wait untill all my data is read. But the problem here is that the readLine never returns! Basically I am good if readLine after some amount of time.

Comment: from the errorstream of the process I launched. the process calls an executable with parameters

Comment: Can you please let me know what are you trying to achieve,  I'm just asking as there may some other easier way to do that.

Comment: Really old question and I dont remember the context exactly now. As far as I Remember, I wanted to read executable error stream using readLine but it was blocking meaning I was not getting control back from readLine unless the executable was killed. 
Using read() function instead of readLine() works though.
I finally used ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true) and that worked, though I had to make changes in my code as error and input stream are now returned as one.
The executable error stream had very less data and it was not flushing it hence readLine was blocking.

Comment: That is good news you were able to solve it. Thanks for reply. XD

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not that the standard error is blocking, but that the standard output is blocking causing the application you are calling to block.

Standard output is normally buffered. If the process you are calling writes less to standard output than the buffer size all is well and it can reach the code that writes to standard error. If the process fills the buffer, its attempt to write to standard output will block and it will never reach the point where it writes to standard error.

This could be why you see it working occasionally - sometimes the standard output does not fill the buffer. It could also be why it works after a long time: eventually the write to standard output times out.

As a demonstration, this simple process always block like you describe on my Windows 8 machine:

```
public class Proc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            System.out.print("More data ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.err.println("An error line");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getErrorStream states the following 
Returns the input stream connected to the error output of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the error output of the process represented by this Process object.
If the standard error of the subprocess has been redirected using ProcessBuilder.redirectError or ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream then this method will return a null input stream.

and the ReadLine states the following
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Based on the explanation provided to the API. readline  waits indefinitely to get line feed or carriage return where as processbuilder returns NULL  that is why readLine terminates for the same.